# Why am I getting this error message when I am using NSTimer to run function every x seconds?

Tags: swift, exception, runtime-error, nstimer

I'm am using an NSTime to run a function every x amount of seconds as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26923825/4726712).

My issue is that I am getting this error message when ever the x amount of seconds is up and it is time to execute the function.

```
2015-04-06 11:55:51.898 myapp[21611:1186926] -[myapp.ViewController getJson(sharedData.jsonUrl)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff48761d60
2015-04-06 11:55:51.902 myapp[21611:1186926] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myapp.ViewController getJson(sharedData.jsonUrl)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff48761d60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101497a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000102fefbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010149ed1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013f69dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013f6578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001018cf844 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013ff6c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013ff285 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013c259d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001013c1bc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001055a0a58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000101d2a580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    12  maybe                               0x0000000100ed55ee top_level_code + 78
    13  myapp                               0x0000000100ed562a main + 42
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001037cb145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I know that the function works as I have tested it on its own.

The code I am using to call the function with the NSTimer is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: self, selector: "getJson(sharedData.jsonUrl)", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

I'm not sure why i am getting this error. I have tried removing the argument from the call and the function itself so that it is exactly the same as the code from the question on SO that I learnt this from but I have had no luck.

I am writing this in swift.

Here is a little bit more info. `getJson` is just a function that downloads a JSON file and appends some of the values to an array. `sharedData` is a singleton class - I am using it to store values that are needed to be used in different view controllers. `jsonUrl` is one of the variable in that class. So `sharedData.jsonUrl` is just getting that variable out of the class.\

EDIT:

This is the code I am trying to use now: 
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
                        0.2,
                        target: self,
                        selector: "getJson:",
                        userInfo: nil, 
                        repeats: true)

The exact error message is:

```
2015-04-06 16:16:56.160 myapp[22712:1284267] -[myapp.settingsViewController getJson:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c88c7d810
2015-04-06 16:16:56.165 myapp[22712:1284267] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myapp.settingsViewController getJson:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c88c7d810'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a491a75 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bfe9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a498d1d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3f09dc ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3f0578 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010a8c9844 __NSFireTimer + 83
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3f96c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3f9285 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3bc59d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a3bbbc6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e59aa58 GSEventRunModal + 161
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ad24580 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    12  myapp                               0x0000000109ed41ce top_level_code + 78
    13  myapp                               0x0000000109ed420a main + 42
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010c7c5145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The get `getJson` function is:

```
func getJson() {
    let urlPath = sharedData.jsonUrl.absoluteString
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath!)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var err: NSError?


        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary

        if err != nil {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let json = JSON(jsonResult)

        var teamCount = json["teamCount"].string! // Number in array
        var teamCountInt: Int = teamCount.toInt()! // Converts to integer

        for index in 0...teamCountInt - 1 { // loop for number in array
            let teamJson = json["teams"][index]["\(index)"].string! //
            sharedData.teamsArray.append(teamJson) // Appends to array in shared data
        }
        println(sharedData.teamsArray) // For debug - delete after
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

This function is uses [Swifty-json](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method getJson() as follows:

```
class SomeGoodClassName {
    func getJson(timer: NSTimer) {
        //Directly use shareData.jsonUrl here to get json data

        //... more code
    }
}
```

NSTimer initialization

```
let jsonLoader = SomeGoodClassName()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.2, target: jsonLoader, selector: "getJson", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post is garbled. The timer call has a malformed markdown link in it so it's hard to tell what we're looking at.

Looking at the error message, though, it shows that your selector is `getJsonTeams(sharedData.jsonUrl)`, which is not valid. You put selects in Objective-C syntax, with no parentheses and no parameters. You selector should probably be `getJsonTeams:`

### EDIT:

Your code should read

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
  0.2, 
  target: self, 
  selector: "getJson:", 
  userInfo: nil, 
  repeats: true)
```

Selectors should be in Objective-C syntax, and should never include parentheses or parameters. If the method takes a single parameter, the selector name should end with a colon.