# How to animate and move player node simultaneously, using sprite kit scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a small ios game with this [joystick library](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick) implemented onto it. My issue is after calculating the direction the joystick is going, I want the character to change to a running animation (I implement the animation using an .sks file). It almost works except after the animation has begun, it stops and doesn't finish until the player lets go at the stick. Some of my code is down below. Any help is appreciated.

Function to setup stick:

```
func setupJoystick() {
    addChild(analogJoyStick)

    analogJoyStick.trackingHandler = { [unowned self] data in
        self.thePlayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.thePlayer.position.x + (data.velocity.x * 0.04), y: self.thePlayer.position.y + (data.velocity.y * 0.04))

        let degrees = self.analogJoyStick.data.angular * 360 / (2 * .pi)
        if degrees > 0 {
         let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkLeft")!
         self.thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
        } else if degrees < 0 {
         let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkRight")!
         self.thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
        }
    }

    analogJoyStick.beginHandler = { [unowned self] in
        let degrees = self.analogJoyStick.data.angular * 360 / (2 * .pi)
        if degrees > 0 {
            let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkLeft")!
            self.thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
        } else if degrees < 0 {
            let walkAnimation:SKAction = SKAction(named: "WalkRight")!
            self.thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
        }
    }

    analogJoyStick.stopHandler = { [unowned self] in
        self.thePlayer.removeAction(forKey: "animating")
    }
}
```

Here is a visual of the coding:
[Spritekit Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGgpj.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I repeat an action forever in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915390/how-would-i-repeat-an-action-forever-in-swift)

Comment: I've tried the answers on that problem before. The results are the same except the animation either plays indefinitely or for the set amount of time.

Comment: Have you tried removing the old animation when you want it to stop?

Comment: This was part of the answer, but @P. van der Laan
 helped me find what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the [joystick library](https://github.com/MitrophD/Swift-SpriteKit-Analog-Stick) instructions and saw two methods (handlers) you can use:

```
var beginHandler: (() -> Void)? // before move
var stopHandler: (() -> Void)? // after move
```

In `beginHandler()` add the (repeated) walk animation:

```
let walkAnimation: SKAction = SKAction(named: theAnimation)!
thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
```

And remove the action in `stopHandler()`

```
thePlayer.removeAction(forKey: "animating")
```

Or using the closures (also from the documentation):

```
joystick.beginHandler = { [unowned self] in
  let walkAnimation: SKAction = SKAction(named: ".sks")!
  self.thePlayer.run(SKAction.repeatForever(walkAnimation), withKey: "animating")
}

joystick.stopHandler = { [unowned self] in
  self.thePlayer.removeAction(forKey: "animating")
}
```

Comment: On a side note, would you happen to know how I could incorporate switching between multiple animations using the handlers?

Comment: In the tracking handler, velocity and angular data are available. Based on the ange you could start different actions. Just make sure the action key is the same - easier to remove in the end.

Comment: I've tried implementing the handlers on the code above, but I can't get the animations to play out completely. When I move my character left or right, the animation stays on the first frame while moving.