# How do I repeat an action from an array of actions continuously

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, random, skaction

I am new to swift and just started learning recently.

Currently, I am having trouble with spawning random objects. One is top and the other is bottom and I want to choose between the two randomly and continue to repeat that action.

What I have so far is I can get the objects to scroll continuously from right to left and then go off the screen. But with my code, it will either spawn the top or the bottom object and then never the other one. It will repeat spawning the one it chooses first.

Not sure if I need to move it from the `didMove(to view: Skview)` function to another one or if there is a better way to code this.

Below is the code I used to try and get it to repeat both of them one by one continuously.

This is the code in the `override func didMove(to view: SKView)` :

```swift
let randomArray = [spawnAndDelayForeverUpObject, spawnAndDelayForeverDownProject]
self.run(randomArray.randomElement()!)
let randomObject = randomArray.randomElement()!
self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(randomObject))
```

I got to confused with my first project so I tried a new project and below is my code for it.`

I still can't understand how to randomly chose like every few seconds for either the red or the blue box to show up instead of both of them. I was on the apple developer website and found the randomization from the gameplay kit programming guide which I will read up on[randomization guide apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/RandomSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH9-SW1)

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
let blueBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blue, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
let redBox = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -9.0)
    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnRedBox), SKAction.wait(forDuration: (5)), SKAction.run(removeRedBox)])))      
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnBlueBox), SKAction.wait(forDuration: (5)), SKAction.run(removeBlueBox)])))
  }

func removeBlueBox() {
    blueBox.removeFromParent()
}
func removeRedBox() {
    redBox.removeFromParent()
}

func spawnBlueBox() {
    print("spawnBlueBoxFuncCalled")

    blueBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: blueBox.size.width, height: blueBox.size.height))
    blueBox.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    blueBox.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    let posTwo = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 50, y: frame.midY + 100), duration: 0.0)

    let Position = posTwo
    let move = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: frame.size.width, dy: 0), duration: 5.0)
    let moveRemoveMoveBack = SKAction.sequence([Position, move])
    let repeatMoving = SKAction.repeatForever(moveRemoveMoveBack)

    blueBox.run(repeatMoving)
    self.addChild(blueBox)

}

func spawnRedBox() {
    print("spawnRedBoxFuncCalled")

    redBox.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: redBox.size.width, height: redBox.size.height))
    redBox.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    redBox.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    let posOne = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.minX + 50, y: frame.midY), duration: 0.0)

    let Position = posOne
    let move = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: frame.size.width, dy: 0), duration: 5.0)
    let moveRemoveMoveBack = SKAction.sequence([Position, move])
    let repeatMoving = SKAction.repeatForever(moveRemoveMoveBack)

    redBox.run(repeatMoving)
    self.addChild(redBox)
    //Array example
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you select an object and assign it to `randomObject` but don't reassign it to a new value for the `run` function. `SKAction.repeatForever` call will repeatedly use the `randomObject` with it's assigned value. You can resolve this issue by repeatedly running the same code. To do this you can move your code to a function and call that function repeatedly with a Timer. Or you can use one of the given answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915390/how-would-i-repeat-an-action-forever-in-swift).

Comment: I started a new project to try this again and used what you mentioned. I played around with it some more and got a blue square and a red square to move left to right. I will add a picture of my code.

Comment: I checked the new code you've added and since you are new to swift I'd suggest following along a few tutorials to get a hang of it. The reason I'm saying this is that there are few things that could be corrected in your code. Such as you don't need to set `physicsBody` property every time you spawn the boxes, same goes for the `move` actions.  You can create the boxes and actions once and repeatedly use them. Also speed up action is another issue and you should ask it as a separate question to get more people to review your code and help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I removed the speed question and will ask it separately. I guess I'll go thru some tutorials before continuing this project.